# HP Scanner not working properly in C# program

Tags: c#

I am facing problem by using HP Scanjet Flow 7000 s3 scanner in my C3 2019 application.

I have developed an application to scan images and it works fine with ***Xerox, Kodak, Avision*** and even ***HP Scanjet Enterprise Flow 7000 s2***. But when I try to run my application with ***HP Scanjet Enterprise Flow 7000 s3*** scanner there is several problems arises.
I am using third party ActiveX https://www.chestysoft.com/ximage/instructions.pdf and I communicate with them. But they told me that they don't have the specific model of scanner and can't help me. I also try to contract with HP by its forum last three months but there is no answer!

So, I decided to post my problem on your site and expecting a solution.

```
                    try
                {

                    if (frmMain.mScanner == "HP ScanJet Flow 7000 s3 TWAIN")
                    {
                        axImageBox1.Acquire();
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (!axImageBox1.ADFLoaded)
                    {
                        if (MessageBox.Show("No paper in tray! Try again?", "Paper Error",      MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error) == DialogResult.No)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        axImageBox1.Acquire();
                        //throw new System.Exception("");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception mErr)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Scanning Error!" + System.Environment.NewLine +
                    Please reboot scanner!" + System.Environment.NewLine + 
                    Press Enter when scanner is ready.", "Scanning Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    mReadError = true;
                    if (frmMain.mScanner == "HP ScanJet Flow 7000 s3 TWAIN")
                    {
                        axImageBox1.TwainImagesToRead = mTotPage;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
```

Please note that all of the scanners return true when I call the property ADFLoaded if there is paper in the input tray and false if the tray is empty. But 7000 S3 driver returns false in both case. For that reason I use above logic to control the S3 scanner. It works fine for a while!!!! But after 10/20 pages scanned the program crashed with the following errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih6wf.png)

Can any one help me to overcome this problem?

Comment: Maybe you should try to scan 10/20 pages with your exe running in the debugger and "break on thrown" set for all exceptions

Comment: If it works fine for a while then crashes I would say it's because of exhausting some limited resource like memory, GDI etc. Are you correctly disposing things that need disposing?

Comment: I can't help but think that, on account of the fact that you've been going round in circles with the HP forums for 3 months, it would have been faster to ship your s3 scanner to the makers of the control you're using so they could fix their code using your scanner

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. But I think none of them is applicable for me. Because the first suggestion I am running my program in debug mode and I have attached the images of the debugger. The second case I have used Garbage Cleaner "GC" for each page scanned!!! The third solution it is impossible to send my device to the makers from my country!!! Thanks again.

Comment: So you want help with a third party control that is not working?

Comment: No. As I find that there is no problem with the ActiveX control because It works fine with different scanners even "HP Scanjet Enterprise 7000 s2" scanner! I think the driver of "HP Scanjet Enterprise 7000 s3" has some bug and for this reason I try to contact HP several times. But they don't response. I am very much astonished that the company like HP not responding this type of problem.

Comment: *"I have used Garbage Cleaner"* - I think you might need to read up on the GC; it's not something you run like defragging a hard disk or vacuuming your house before the in-laws visit

Comment: I have removed the GC part from my code and before crushing the debugger shows the memory use is 168 MB for only 11 images. Second time it shows 267 for only 24 images. Third time 171 MB = 11, 4th time 248=21. Do you still think that there is problem in memory management? Then why all other including "HP Scanjet Enterprise 7000 s2" scanners scans very fine? Please tell your opinion.